# Google Cloud Dataflow access .txt file on cloud storage

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

If I have a .txt file stored on GCS containing a list of words that will be used as part of a `beam.Filter` can this list be accessed dynamically within my apache beam pipeline?  I know that I can define this list as a global variable within the pipeline, but I'm not sure how to read in the whole file into a list and if there are any beam tricks to accomplish this.  Any suggestions? Here is my current implementation which is not working..

```
def boolean_terms(word, term_list):
  if word in term_list:
    return (word, 1)
  else:
    return (word, 0)

# side table
filter_terms = p | beam.io.ReadFromText(path_to_gcs_txt_file)

words = ...

filtered_words = words | beam.FlatMap(lambda x: 
    [boolean_terms(word, filter_terms) for word in x])
```

I get the following error "TypeError: argument of type '_InvalidUnpickledPCollection' is not iterable"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the list of words as a [side input](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#side-inputs). I believe the `beam.Filter` transform supports usage of side inputs from the filter function in exactly the same way as `FlatMap` and `ParDo` in the examples by that link.

Something like:

```
words | beam.Filter(lambda x, filter_terms: word in filter_terms,
                    filter_terms=pvalue.AsList(p | beam.io.ReadFromText(path)))
```

Comment: Thanks! I think I'm closer, but it still doesn't appear to be working for me. Am I missing something?

Comment: Ah I think I figured it out -- I needed to add `pvalue.AsList(filter_terms)` to get this working correctly